# Format cell by adding "+" in dollar positive values without affecting formulas (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I have the following values:

[image]

And I would like positive values to come with the "+" sign before the dollar symbol, I know this can be done by adding `IF > 0, "+"&`

But in this way, it affects the calculations of all other cells that depend on the results obtained in those cells.

I wonder if there is any way to format this cell without affecting via formula.

I tried to put:

`"+"$0;"-"$0;$`

In custom coins, but it didn't work out.

Comment: +$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;$0.00 works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this under custom number format:

```
+$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;$0.00
```

[image: 0]